# White lines in windows start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I'm seeing white lines in the border of the windows 10 start menu when some programs are opened (like google chrome).

Here is a screenshot of those annoying lines :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Ue9urLI.png]

You can see them in the bottom (over the task bar) and right corner (they are not really visible on the right corner due to the white background), and even though they are really small, they are annoying me quite a bit.

I found that they are only visible when I'm using a custom display scaling level (130%) and that if I choose to use a regular scaling level of like 125%, they aren't visible, but the problem is that google chrome's top panel becomes really small with this scaling and that it gets to the upper scaling at 126% (which is a custom scaling).

[image: http://i.imgur.com/O2xLp8T.png]

Is there a way to erase those lines while keeping my custom scaling or is there a way to make google chrome's top panel bigger at a scaling of 125% ?